# How can i remove html tags from a text and store it in EL?

Tags: javascript, html, json, atg, atg-dynamo

i am getting data using atg dsp:valueof tag with 'valueishtml' property set to true. I need to pass this data retrieved i.e. without any html tags to a json variable via EL. Can someone guide me how this can be done? . Below is an example of what i need to do.Please note this is not a code.

```
var mydatawithouthtml = <dsp:valueof param="product.data" valueishtml="true"/>

<json:property name="data" value="${mydatawithouthtml}" />
```

currently "product.data" contains html tags which are getting passed to json. need json data without any html tags.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be to develop your own `tagconverter`. A simple way to achieve is as follow:

```
package com.acme.tagconverter;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import atg.droplet.TagAttributeDescriptor;
import atg.droplet.TagConversionException;
import atg.droplet.TagConverter;
import atg.droplet.TagConverterManager;
import atg.nucleus.GenericService;
import atg.nucleus.ServiceException;
import atg.servlet.DynamoHttpServletRequest;

public class StripHTMLConverter extends GenericService implements TagConverter {

    private Pattern tagPattern;

    @Override
    public void doStartService() throws ServiceException {
        TagConverterManager.registerTagConverter(this);
    }

    public String convertObjectToString(DynamoHttpServletRequest request, Object obj, Properties attributes) throws TagConversionException {
        return tagPattern.matcher(obj.toString()).replaceAll("");
    }

    public Object convertStringToObject(DynamoHttpServletRequest request, String str, Properties attributes) throws TagConversionException {
        return str;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return "striphtml";
    }

    public TagAttributeDescriptor[] getTagAttributeDescriptors() {
        return new TagAttributeDescriptor[0];
    }

    public void setTagPattern(String tagPattern) {
        this.tagPattern = Pattern.compile(tagPattern);
    }

    public String getTagPattern() {
        return tagPattern.pattern();
    }

}
```

This is then referenced via a component properties file, containing the pattern:

```
$class=com.acme.tagconverter.StripHTMLConverter
tagPattern=<[^>]+>
```

Obviously this assumes that everything between a starting '<' and ending '>' should be removed. You can work on the RegEx yourself to find a better pattern.

You should also register the TagConverter in the Initial.properties

```
$class=atg.nucleus.InitialService
$scope=global

initialServices+=\
    /com/acme/tagconverter/StripHTMLConverter
```

Now you should be able to use it as you intended.

```
var mydatawithouthtml = '<dsp:valueof param="product.data" converter="striphtml"/>'
```